# THREE.js: How to achieve a slanted divider view?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to achieve a slanted divider effect with WebGL. The desired outcome is something like a view with 1 interactive divider (slanted) at the middle that allows the user to drag and view a mountain terrain with different colours.

The effect should look like this: [slanted draggable divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ApE8.png)

I have experimented based on a few examples I found online, but both methods used THREE.WebGLRenderer.setScissor() for the effect, and the results are rectangles.

May I know what are the alternatives to achieve the effect? Stencil buffer and masking? Better THREE.Camera setup? glViewport?

I have tried using react-three/drei's View and changing the CSS clip-path property, but it seems to stay rectangular.

Examples:

- https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_scenes_comparison
- https://codepen.io/sunnysideup8888/pen/poVvyvR

SetScissor implementation in the examples:

```
  renderer.setScissor(0, 0, splitPos, sizes.height);
  renderer.render(sceneL, camera);

  renderer.setScissor(splitPos, 0, sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.render(sceneR, camera);
```

Comment: I did something similar, using on-screen UV: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cyber-ethno-wind-simulation/38201

Comment: @prisoner849, thanks for the example! I'll test it out and get back here with an update.